# Lisp OODB with SQL backend - or good ORM

Tags: orm, lisp

Are there any good Lisp OODBs implemented on top of SQL databases, or good Lisp ORM solutions?  I want the administrative features and IT-familiarity of a RDMS, but still get the power of OO.  Any recommendations?  The state of the art, at least in non-commercial solutions, seems not to have advanced much in the past few years.

I'd rather not have to hack CLSQL myself to add things like transaction support, multiple inheritance, or lazy loading.

Answer (score 2):

Try [cl-perec](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-perec/).

Comment: What happens if pclasses are redef-ed?  This can be across Lisp instance lifetimes.  Are pclass instances created under the old definition lost to the new codebase?